# Spring authentication provider ignores my details

Tags: java, spring

I was wondering, why I never get my User object from the Authentication object using getDetails. I only get the username using getPrincipal.

Debugging my project I have seen a behaviour, that I had not expected.

I use Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE.

The security-app-context.xml contains this configuration

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

My userDetailsService is this

```
@Service
class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService, InitializingBean {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            final User search = new User();
            search.setUsername(username);
            final User user = service.get(search, null);
            if (user != null) {
                UserDetailsModel model = new UserDetailsModel(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                    getGrantedAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
                model.setDetails(user);
                return model;
            }
        } catch (final Throwable th) {
            log.error("", th);
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Bad credentials");
    }
```

As one can see, the details are set with the current user data from my service.

Debugging it from the point, when it returns the model, we return to

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider line 101
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider line 132
```

Within the second class there is a method createSuccessAuthentication in line 190 that is finally executed.

```
protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication,
        UserDetails user) {
    // Ensure we return the original credentials the user supplied,
    // so subsequent attempts are successful even with encoded passwords.
    // Also ensure we return the original getDetails(), so that future
    // authentication events after cache expiry contain the details
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal,
            authentication.getCredentials(), authoritiesMapper.mapAuthorities(user.getAuthorities()));
    result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

    return result;
}
```

In line 198 it adds details to the result (an Authentication) but it does not take it from the provided UserDetails but from the authentication, that does not contain details.

Is this a configuration problem, my fault or is this a bug in Spring?

Comment: Is your loadUserByUsername() implementation called by the framework when you authenticate ? Actually, you implementation throws exception in case of bad credentials: maybe, it should be better to define a custom authentication provider in this case. As described here (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-userdetailsservice), your service must only retrieve data, not perform authentication.

Comment: As I wrote it is called. I started debugging in that method. In addition, my UserDetailsService implements the standard interface, that throws a UsernameNotFoundException, so why shouldn't it throw it if the user name is not found?

Comment: Do you have a toString() method in your UserDetailsModel class ? Normally, the UserDetails object should be returned when calling getPrincipal() from the Authentication object. See  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal()

Comment: I don't want a to String of something. I need the User Data, that where already requested from the datastore. No need, to do it a second time...

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my previous comment: I mean that the UserDetails object built in your service should be returned by the getPrincipal() method, not the getDetails() method (see the link to the spring doc in the previous comment). This is the reason why you get null when you call getDetails(). I asked about the toString() just to confirm (or not) the way you get this username info: that is still unclear to me, maybe you could put the code where you retrieve the authentication object ?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was my missing link. getPrincipal returns my UserDetailsModel, that contains the User :)

Comment: Can you add it as answer, so I can vote for it?

Comment: You're welcome, I've added the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getPrincipal() method returns your implementation of UserDetails, not the getDetails() method.